# Factor $x^4+1$ as product of two factors

Tags: factoring, partial-fractions

I want to do partial fraction expansion on $$\frac{1}{x^4+1}.$$
But how to I factor the denominator so that I get a product of two factors?

Comment: Then you should find the roots of $x^4+1$. Clearly there are no real roots, so you should work over the complex numbers.

Comment: Do you want to factor $x^4+1$ or the inverse of this?

Answer (score 5):

Trying
$(x^2+ax+1)(x^2-ax+1)
=x^4+x^2(2-a^2)+1
$,
we find that
$a^2=2$
works.

Comment: Maybe you should explain the choice of the coefficients.

Comment: After some experience, you develop a feeling for what might work, If it doesn't, I often show it anyway so that others don't waste time on it.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

$x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2-2x^2$

$=(x^2+1+x\sqrt{2})(x^2+1-x\sqrt{2})$

Comment: totally get how you get the first one but the second?

Comment: $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Answer (score 1):

The roots of $x^4+1$ are complex, pairwise conjugate, namely $\dfrac{\pm1\pm i}{\sqrt2}$ (they are the square roots of $\pm i$). Then developing and using Vieta's formulas,

$$(x-r_{++})(x-r_{+-})(x-r_{-+})(x-r_{--})=(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2x+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

note that $$x^4+1=x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2=(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt{2}x)^2=(x^2+1-\sqrt{2}x)(x^2+1+\sqrt{2}x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Every quartic polynomial factors as the product of two quadratic ones. As both the coefficients of $x^4$ and $x^0$ are $1$, the factorization must be of the form

$$(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1).$$

Developing, you get

$$x^4+(a+b)x^3+(ab+2)x^2+(a+b)x+1.$$

Clearly, $a=-b=\pm\sqrt2$.